# What is the best way to implement different versions of the same function?

Tags: python, function

Suppose I have the following function -

```
def add(a, b):
    if isinstance(a, (float,int)) and isinstance(b, (float,int)):
        return (a+b)
    else:
        raise TypeError("Invalid Parameters")
```

Now this function is used in two cases -

i) When a user calls it and might give input other than float or real.

ii) When the function is used internally (many times) and I am completely sure that the input parameters would only be int or float.

How can I avoid the useless type checks when using the function internally?

Alternatively,
What is the best way of writing, the above function and the following function as a single function?

```
def add(a, b):
    return (a+b)
```

The above function is simple but there may be a case when there are number of checks and the function is quite large. In such a case, how can I avoid writing the same function twice?

Comment: What's wrong with the type checks?

Comment: They will cause unnecessary overhead in a complex case when there are many unwanted checks but I am sure that the input is valid.

Comment: I guess you *could* add a third, optional parameter.  If you don't want the error checks, call it with True, but the default is False?

Comment: @YashuSeth in the first case, what do you want your function to do if the input are not int or float?

Comment: @njzk2 raise a value error sorry I did not mention it.

Comment: You are tied to: 1. add another argument and condition as @zondo said; 2. declare two different functions (the typechecker calls the internal); 3. Use just one function and evaluate a+b+0 (although this could cause a false positive if a and b are compatible objects by `__add__` or `__radd__`, and the result of the operation is compatible with 0 by `__add__`).

Comment: @YashuSeth what is wrong with not making the checks, and having the `+` raise an error on its own?

Comment: @njzk2 `+` won't raise when used with strings or lists.

Comment: @njzk2 Because this is a simple example what happens when the function is complex and there are a number of type checks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be to have to functions that you use depending on the use case, in case you can't rely on the try/catch pattern due to other reasons (but I would suggest it if you can):

```
def add_check(a, b):
    if isinstance(a, (float, int)) and isinstance(b, (float, int)):
        return add(a, b)

def add(a, b):
    return (a+b)
```

If you just want one function you'll have to tell it somehow when to do the checks and when not to, perhaps with an additional parameter:

```
def add(a, b, type_check=False):
    if type_check:
        if not isinstance(a, (float, int)) or not isinstance(b, (float, int)):
            raise TypeError("Invalid Parameters")
    return add(a, b)
```

Comment: That is the whole point. How can I avoid writing the same function twice?

Comment: @YashuSeth if you want only one function you'll have to tell it if it should do the additional check or not in some way. I've updated the answer with such example.

Comment: @oloform I get it and now I think this is the only better way to do it.

Comment: With the three-parameters version you always have to pass an additional parameter and check its value. That carries some overhead too and I am not sure it is better than what you had before. I didn't timeit anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Leave the function as is, use just `+` when you do not need or want type checking.

> i) When a user calls it and might give input other than float or real.

Use `c = add(a, b)`

> ii) When the function is used internally (many times) and I am completely sure that the input parameters would only be int or float.

Use `c = a + b`

You only need to write one function and do not incurre in more overhead than is strictly necessary.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: The add function was just an example. What if the function is complex with a number of type checks?

Comment: Then the question is too broad. The answer depends on the function and usage patterns.